# 拡張機能のiconを指定した箇所に表示されるエラーの意味が分からない

Tags: vscode

簡単な拡張機能を作成したのですが、iconの指定のところでエラーが表示されます。(下図参照)

[image: エラーメッセージ]

エラーメッセージは出てますが、拡張機能の説明のところに画像は表示されています。
気にしなければこのままでもいいのですが、なんとなく気になります。
エラーを解消するためにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下リンク先の Issue が関連しそうです。

[Warning in package.json when specifying icon without https repository · Issue #90900 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90900)

表示されているのはエラーではなくワーニング (警告) だと思います。

拡張機能を配布する際、指定したアイコンがオンラインのリポジトリ上に存在し、かつ (HTTPではなく) HTTPS 経由で参照可能な必要がある、と言っているように思われます。

[package.json with a png icon shows a seemingly bogus warning · Issue #30434 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30434)

> ```js
> "icon": "LanguageCCPP_color_128x.png",
> "repository": {
>     "type": "git",
>     "url": "https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools.git"
> },
> ```

Comment: アイコンはurlに実在する必要がなく、urlが通ればいいみたいな感じです。
適当にhttps://github.com/microsoft/vscodeとして追加したら警告が出なくなりました。
本来はこんなことじゃダメなんでしょうけど、アイコンなんでこれで解決とします。